# How to make a image url active in Views Table

Tags: views, uri, theming

I've got a table with a column for images. The field display is link (see screenshot). For some reason it doesn't display as an active link. Any ideas on how to accomplish that?[image: Screenshot of table]

Comment: What's an "active link" in this context?

Comment: Please keep your browser's window under 600px width when taking screenshots - that's the width images here will be downscaled to. Now what you posted is not readable. Also, consider installing FireShot or similar plugin for your browser, to take a screenshot of only the page you are asking about. We don't really need to see your tabs ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that this is a file field and that you chose `URL to File` as the field formatter. You would then need to scroll down and expand `Rewrite results`, tick the box for `Output this field as a link`, and in the box for `Link path` you need to enter the views token replacement for your field name, which you can find by expanding the section below titled `Replacement patterns`—in your case it is likely to be `[field_scan]`

Once you enter that, you should have what you are calling "active link" which in more precise terms would be called an hyperlink or anchor tag.

Comment: Great, glad you got what you were after. Would you kindly mark this as answered?